# Avoid sample entity creation while using Liferay Service Builder

Tags: java, maven, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-service-builder

Kind of a newbie to portals and liferay (6.2 Community Edition).

I am creating a service builder portlet with Maven. Instead of using the IDE i am building it via the command line.

I ran the command(s) in my workspace

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and once the project was generated I ran the command(s) for service builder inside the project directory

```
mvn liferay:build-service
```

The service builder creates a sample entity `Foo` every time I run the the command for the first time after generating the archetype. **Is there a command to avoid creation of sample entity when running the service-builder for the first time.**

I know how to do that in the IDE but couldn't figure out the command for that incase I am using the terminal.

Comment: Did not get what you mean by avoiding Foo entity creation. build-service will generate code for entities defined in service.xml. If you do not want Foo entity, then please remove it from WEB-INF/service.xml

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your input, i believe overtime you generate archetypes, it adds a sample entity to your service.xml file. I wasn't removing that entity from my service.xml before running the service builder. The issue is not sorted. Thanks